# Calculate the speed of $r(t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the speed of $r(t)=(4t+3,5t−1,5−t)$ at $t=2$.

$\|v(t)\|=\|(4,5,-1)\|=(16+25+1)^{1/2}=(42)^{1/2}=6.48$

How should the $t=2$ be incorporated if there is no variable left when $r(t)$ is derived?

Comment: What $r(t)$ describes here is a straight line, so it has a constant gradient w.r.t. $t$, and therefore its speed never changes.

Comment: @J.Marshall -- A straight line can have varying speed. $t$ is not necessarily arclength.

Comment: That's the essence of constant functions. $f(x) = 4$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You're right. With this parametrisation the speed is constant, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed is constant; it has the same value for all $t$.